# Custom provider for http header values as a Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring

I have big legacy project with a lot of code and logic.

I have many similar methods in my controller:

```
public void someEndpoint(
    @RequestHeader("flowId") String flowId,
    @RequestHeader("someAnotherParam") String someAnotherParam,
    @RequestHeader("customerId") String customerId
) {
   //pass all arguments to services
}
```

Every controller method has this three arguments.

This three arguments are passed to another services, and next to another services and another services as method argument.
Whole code is a little messy from this reason.These three arguments are everywhere.

Can I write something like a provider for this three parameter? Some service like:

```
@Service
class RequestContextProvider {
    public RequestContext getRequestContext() {
        //some logic
    }
}

class RequestContext {
    String flowId,
    String someAnotherParam,
    String customerId
}
```

And how to do that using spring?

Comment: If these only concern headers, you can write a filter that extracts the headers and fills them into your `RequestContext` which can be a request scoped bean. You don't need to provider, you can then simply inject the `RequestContext` in places you need it.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, but i need to inject my flowId, someAnotherParam and customerId to singleton beans

Comment: Which is why you would inject a scoped bean into the singleton, which is the purpose of scoped beans.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that i can inject requestBean into singletonBean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RequestContextHolder class as below:

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
        
String flowId = request.getHeader("flowId");
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. What do you think, Is it bad or good pattern to do it in this way?

Comment: Don't use this outside of a controller, else you are trying your service layer (or even more) to the web, which is what you want to prevent.